# How can I avoid the situation in xcode running app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, multithreading

When I run the app in xcode,it always show the case as below and my app on iphone simulator was stopped in a view,I can do nothing.Can any one tell me how to avoid this case appearing,thanks.
[image: When I run the app in xcode,it always show the case as below and my app on iphone simulator was stopped in a view,I can do nothing.Can any one tell me how to avoid this case appearing,thanks]

[image: My app was stopped in this view,I checked my code carefully and did not find any error.]

here are the code in warning.

```
   (void)processCollision:(UIImageView *)bricks{
score+=10;
scoreLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d" , score];
if (ballMovement.x>0&& bricks.frame.origin.x-ball.center.x<=4) {
    ballMovement.x=-ballMovement.x;
}else if(ballMovement.x<0&&ball.center.x-(bricks.frame.origin.x+bricks.frame.size.width)<=4){
    ballMovement.x=-ballMovement.x;
}

if (ballMovement.y>0&&bricks.frame.origin.y-ball.center.y<=4) {
    ballMovement.y=-ballMovement.y;
}else if(ballMovement.y<0&&ball.center.y-(bricks.frame.origin.y+bricks.frame.size.height)<=4){
    ballMovement.y=-ballMovement.y;
    bricks.alpha-=0.1;
}
```

}

Comment: I did not understand by "case"? What is case?

Comment: Yes, so my question is how to avoid the situation in xcode?

Comment: does the console have some output? can you post it here?

Comment: Here are the error output:Couldn't register stream.IVBricker with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does it say in the console?

[image]

EDIT:

The Error:

> Couldn't register stream.IVBricker with the bootstrap server. Error:
>   unknown error code. This generally means that another instance of this
>   process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb) –

This can be fixed by restarting your computer.

Comment: Couldn't register stream.IVBricker with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)

Comment: Thank you ,I restart my computer and it works.But i don't know why this situation will arise

Comment: Several things can cause this but mostly it isn't avoidable. All it means is that the process was never completely terminated for whatever reason. If this helped you, please mark as correct.

Answer (score 5):

I can't help with the initial bug, but the aftermath, where you get the
"This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.", message and Xcode won't debug anymore, is easily fixed.

This error occurs because the debugging monitor process on your device has become disconnected and no new debug processes can be started for that particular app while the debugging monitor is still present.

The solution is NOT to restart your computer, but to restart your DEVICE.

Hold down power and home buttons at the same time. 
Ignore everything that happens until you see the Apple Logo, then let go.

You will find Xcode will now debug correctly again.

No need to shut down Xcode, restart your computer or anything else.

Comment: Nice catch - I can confirm the fix is restart your DEVICE not your computer

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception breakpoint to break into debugger when your code throws exception which is causing this problem. That way you can find and correct that code.

In the breakpoint pane (left in your screenshot, the second last icon button) you can add break point by clicking plus icon to left-bottom. Once breakpoint is added, run your program from debugger.

Comment: Here are the error out output:Couldn't register stream.IVBricker with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)