# Xcode 4.3.3 : how to assign a view controller while initializing

Tags: xcode, ios5, storyboard

Hy all.
Since i am using IOS 5 , therefore i am using storyboard. 
In the older versions, i could easily write `initWithNibName:@"Details"`, and it worked like a charm.
Now in storyboard, and since i am not using any XIB file, i need to do the same thing.
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Get the selected country
    NSString *selectedAuthors = [theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
    Details *dvController = [[Details alloc] initWithNibName:@"Details" bundle:nil];

    dvController.selectedAuthors = selectedAuthors;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

My new Snippet :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Get the selected country
    NSString *selectedAuthors = [theauthors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard.storyboard" bundle:nil];
    Details *dvController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"]; //Or whatever identifier you have defined in your storyboard


    //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
    //Details *dvController = [[Details alloc] init/*WithNibName:@"Details" bundle:nil*/];

    dvController.selectedAuthors = selectedAuthors;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
}
```

Application Log :

```
2012-07-17 16:30:15.760 AuthorsApp[6534:f803] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <AuthorVC: 0x6857ba0>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
2012-07-17 16:30:16.167 AuthorsApp[6534:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x6867750>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'Details''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1595022 0x1726cd6 0x500fef 0x3151 0x1675c5 0x1677fa 0x9fc85d 0x1569936 0x15693d7 0x14cc790 0x14cbd84 0x14cbc9b 0x147e7d8 0x147e88a 0xd6626 0x1dc2 0x1d35)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Latest Application Log:

```
2012-07-17 16:35:15.352 AuthorsApp[6600:f803] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <AuthorVC: 0x688d810>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
2012-07-17 16:35:15.912 AuthorsApp[6600:f803] Everything is ok now !
(lldb)
```

Final Log

```
Couldn't register com.test.erc.AuthorsApp with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instantiate the controller that is located in your storyboard like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil];
Details *dvController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details"]; //Or whatever identifier you have defined in your storyboard
```

---

Another option since you're using Storyboards would be using [segues](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the transitions. [Here is a nice example](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219). One thing that you get for free with segues is that the destination controller gets instantiated automatically for you. The delegate method looks like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Details"]){
         Details *dvController = (Details *)[segue destinationViewController];
         // Pass any data to destination controller
         // The transition is handled by the segue and defined in the Storyboard ('push' for example)
     }
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is a screenshot for easy reference:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help , but none of the two methods worked..maybe i m doing something wrong, could you write a code snippet using the second method?

Comment: @EliasRahme Did you pass the correct storyboard name & your controller's identifier in the first example? For the second one I have already included a link with a fully working example.

Comment: yes i did, my story board is named MainStoryboard, and plz find in the above my new code snippet maybe i am missing something..but the app automatically crashes

Comment: I even tried with the name MainStoryBoard without the extension

Comment: @EliasRahme You do not need the `.storyboard` extension. It should be just `MainStoryBoard`. Also please make absolutely sure that your controller's identifier in the storyboard is correct. If it's not then an exception is raised.

Comment: My view controller is Details , done by the old fashion way and i am absolutely sure from his name , in the class name and everywhere.
but when you told me this i double checked the log.
It seems that Xcode doesn't recognize this class. Please find in the edited version the log of the application and thank you in advance

Comment: @EliasRahme Yes the identifier is the culprit. Please see my screenshot. You have to set `identifier` on your controller (this is not the same as the class of the controller)

Comment: I did check with your screenshot in which i thank you a lot! i did make the modifications as you suggested. The application is still crashing but the log report is different. please check the latest edit and thank you in advance

Comment: @EliasRahme I just see 'Everything is ok now !' in your logs. Are you sure that this is not just a stop on a breakpoint?

Comment: Everything is ok is a custom NSLog assuring me that i can connect to sqlite database, and no i am disabling all breakpoints :S

Comment: @EliasRahme If you're using ARC then just also drop `[dvController release];`

Comment: I dropped it, and a new error log is appearing , i tried to reset conf settings of the simulator, restarting X-code and everything even cleaning the project, but this new log appeared :S please check the new edit :S i am sry for taking your time

Comment: Do you have any idea why this new log is appearing\

Comment: @EliasRahme Absolutely not (apart from the obvious message). Hmm I guess we'll have to do a little research for that :P

Comment: @EliasRahme Apparently you have to restart your computer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655489/how-can-i-avoid-the-situation-in-xcode-running-app

Comment: hahah thank you for your help , and if any updates comes up please keep me in touch :)

Comment: and as for the original problem...do u have any idea what to do next? I'm really lost \

Comment: @EliasRahme Did you restarted and still crashing? I believe that you should be fine with the code now, unless there is a bug in another part of your code. I would strongly suggest you to put a breakpoint and step through the code in order to see what really causes the problem.

Comment: I will restart now, and check this matter tomorrow i thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you sir!! it worked like a charm ! :D i really appreciate your help , and if you can check this other link i am having trouble with i would really appreciate it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517475/xcode-search-bar-filtering